# Destination host unreachable (ICMP), although a simple ping can reach the same host

Tags: centos, networking

I've setup some application using port 179 (BGP) on two CentOS hosts which are directly connected to each other, but they seem to be unable to establish a connection, so I launched `tcpdump` to check whats going on:

```
$ tcpdump --interface ens20 -nn
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens20, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
09:10:53.715981 IP 10.0.5.2.46577 > 10.0.5.3.179: Flags [S], seq 4065918158, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2186333430 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
09:10:53.716897 IP 10.0.5.3 > 10.0.5.2: ICMP host 10.0.5.3 unreachable - admin prohibited filter, length 68
09:10:59.179303 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.5.2 tell 10.0.5.3, length 28
09:10:59.179322 ARP, Reply 10.0.5.2 is-at 3e:63:58:e9:a3:d9, length 28
```

Ok, so it looks like the other host isn't even reachable. That's rather strange, because I already tried to ping and am certain it worked. So, one more try of `ping -I ens20 10.0.5.2` on host `10.0.5.3`. (And, just to be sure I tried the reverse with same effect too.)

```
09:11:40.186862 IP 10.0.5.2 > 10.0.5.3: ICMP echo request, id 3941, seq 1, length 64
09:11:40.187309 IP 10.0.5.3 > 10.0.5.2: ICMP echo reply, id 3941, seq 1, length 64
09:11:41.233187 IP 10.0.5.2 > 10.0.5.3: ICMP echo request, id 3941, seq 2, length 64
09:11:41.233570 IP 10.0.5.3 > 10.0.5.2: ICMP echo reply, id 3941, seq 2, length 64
09:11:45.260415 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.5.2 tell 10.0.5.3, length 28
09:11:45.260438 ARP, Reply 10.0.5.2 is-at 3e:63:58:e9:a3:d9, length 28
09:11:45.457134 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.5.3 tell 10.0.5.2, length 28
09:11:45.457418 ARP, Reply 10.0.5.3 is-at ae:e9:68:81:26:dc, length 28
```

Great, `ping` works, I can reach the host. Ok, next idea: can I reach the other host at port 179 myself, for example through `telnet -b 10.0.5.2 10.0.5.3 179` (from `10.0.5.2`). Nope, `telnet: connect to address 10.0.5.3: No route to host`. But is the port even open? Yes, `telnet -b 10.0.5.2 10.0.5.3 179` works (from `10.0.5.3`). `tcpdump` shows the same error for the telnet experiment as the application above.

For the sake of completeness, here is the interface configuration too (`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens20`):

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=ens20
UUID=7f8ca407-e96a-497e-865c-972a6f1940d6
DEVICE=ens20
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=10.0.5.2
PREFIX=24
```

*(There is another interface configured too on the same host, but that is configured to use an external IP address and should not interfere with the 10.0.5.0/24, I hope.)*

There is no firewall enabled on those hosts (clean CentOS minimal installation) and these hosts are directly connected. I have no idea why one request wouldn't be allowed to pass through, while the other isn't, but probably related to the usage of multiple interfaces. **Where would you look to get more details on whats going on?**

Comment: It is blocked by a firewall very probably, because the `firewalld` service is enabled by default on CentOS. Check with `systemctl status firewalld`. Proper way to fix this problem is to create a rule to permit the traffic.

Comment: Damn, how could I have missed that. Yes, `firewalld` was running and disabling it made the application able to establish a connection. (Feel free to post that comment as answer, so I can set it to the accepted answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ICMP packets with code "destination unreachable" and type "administratively prohibited" are generated by packet filters, not the TCP/IP stack.

Given that, the status of `nftables` (or legacy `iptables`) should make the cause clear.

As posted in the comments, CentOS ships with `firewalld` enabled by default. This package provides the `firewall-cmd` command for configuring the firewall. A new rule should be added to open the destination port.

Of course, disabling the `firewalld` is also possible, but only if you understand the risks.